# Submission for IEEE-template-based paper in Arxiv

Tags: peer-review, ieee, publications

Can we submit our journal paper(formatted in IEEE-paper style) in arXiv which is already submitted in IEEE journal for review(the paper's decision is not yet made)? or it's mandatory to publish the paper only in arxiv format
Regards

Comment: You should first check whether a preprint is allowed to be submitted or not by the journal. Few Journals do not allow it. Otherwise there is no template restriction on arXiv.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main points to your question that I will address.

**IEEE policy for preprints**

For IEEE, you are in general allowed to post the submitted version of the paper on arXiv while it is undergoing peer review (provided your specific journal doesn't have policies prohibiting that, e.g. if it is a double-blind journal). This is outlined in the IEEE author's rights document (https://www.ieee.org/publications/rights/rights-policies.html, with a nice summary here http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Article-Sharing-and-Posting-Policies.pdf). Specifically, the policy says:

> 3. IEEE seeks to maximize the rights of its authors and their employers to post preprint versions of an article on the author’s personal Web site, on a server operated by the author’s employer, or on a server operated by an approved not-for-profit third party as specified in 8.1.9.G.2 below.

arXiv is one of the approved third-party hosting servers for the IEEE.

The main stipulation is that once the article has been accepted and issued a DOI, the posted preprint needs to be updated to include that information, as stated in the preprint policy:

> D. E-PRINTS
> Before submitting an article to an IEEE publication, authors frequently post preprints of their articles to their own Web site, their employer’s site, or to another server that invites constructive comment from colleagues and provides a publication time stamp. Upon submission of an article to IEEE, an author is required to transfer copyright in the article to IEEE, and the author must update any previously posted version of the article with a prominently displayed IEEE copyright notice (as shown in 8.1.9.B). Upon publication of an article by IEEE, the author must replace any previously posted electronic versions of the article with either (1) the full citation to the IEEE work with a Digital Object Identifier (DOI), or (2) the accepted version only with the DOI (not the IEEE-published version). IEEE shall make available to each author the preprint version of the article that the author can post and that includes the DOI, IEEE’s copyright notice, and a notice indicating that the article has been accepted for publication by IEEE.

This means that you are allowed to post the author-accepted version of the manuscript on arXiv (i.e. the one from after all peer-review is completed but before you submit the final files to IEEE for their formatting), but it must contain a link to the DOI of the IEEE manuscript. arXiv provides a mechanism to include the DOI on a submission, so you need to update the submission to have that.

**Format of papers for arXiv**

There is no "arXiv template" that must be followed, and so the exact formatting of the paper is entirely left to you as the author. If you want, you can use the same IEEE template you used for the original journal submission, or you could change it to be a different type (e.g. simply the LaTex article class, SIAM template, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

No, that is often not allowed. Once an article is published, it becomes the property of the publisher (check with them first). In your case though, it may still be problematic after it is accepted. Therefore, you may come into problems if you make it available on ArXiv, i.e. if the content is usually behind a paywall but you make it available for free on ArXiv.

Comment: This is not true for IEEE papers, which the poster is specifically asking about. IEEE specifically lets you post to arXiv and still transfer the copyright to IEEE with no future problems (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

ArXiv has no "format". You can publish using whatever format you want there.

Do check your journal's preprint policy though, because they might ask for certain things once your paper is accepted (e.g. to credit them as the copyright holder).